# images are not shown, fetched from db

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

i am facing issue displaying images.

Initially images are posted and saved successfully in MongoDb , you can see in below image[image: saved imageUrl in db]

then images are fetched from db and then displayed  ,but while displaying the images are broken and following error is shown in console..

(Note:- i am using reactjs in frontend)

[image: console img]

and this is code to fetch data from backend

```
const getAllPostInfo = async () => {
setLoading();
if (localStorage.token) {
  setToken(localStorage.token);
}
try {
  const res = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/post",
  });
  // console.log(`getting all post`, res.data.status[0].posts);
  const resData = res.data.status[0].posts;
  dispatch({ type: GET_ALL_POSTS, payload: resData });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.response);
  dispatch({ type: POST_ERRORS, payload: err.response.errors });
}
```

};

this is reducer action code

```
   case GET_ALL_POSTS:
  console.log("action payload in post reducer", action.payload);
  return {
    ...state,
    post_info: action.payload,
    post_loading: false,
    errors: null,
  };
```

react code -fetching single post and displaying

```
 const PostItem = ({ post }) => {
```

const { title, imageUrl, description } = post;
....
}

the below image, one can see post being fetched ... (in browser react puglin) but images are not displayed ... i don't understand where i am going wrong ...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your images are being stored as file-paths and not filenames. You need to remove that 'images/' before the filename in the imageUrl datapoint.

Comment: thanks Kibuika Codes .. thats working  .. but i did not get how its working...  my way of seeing/ understanding is that ,i am instructing to find those images in images folder which is present outside of current/client root folder... my question is how it is finding the images if only filename is specified ???  Thanks once again

Comment: yes @Naresh. that is how MongoDB stores images. Unlike firebase which actually stores image URLs. That filename acts as a reference to the actual image content.